# How to make imageView clickable from OnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, clickable-image

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) 
        {

         // My code is here. I want make my image clickable. I don't want make it clickable in my CustomAdapter getView() method because it doesn't allows me open DialogFragment from there.
         // I already setted in xml of image clickable="true" and focusable = "false"
         //I'll admit for any help and thanks in advance

        }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question

Answer (score 3):

If you take image Onclick from adapter,you cannot take setOnItemClickListener from listview event.I suggested you may take Onclick and insteadof setOnItemClickListener take Onclick from adapter.

Comment: Yes but if i'm taking onClick from my adapter into getView() method i can't get there fragment manager for opening DialogFragment

Comment: Put toast code on onclick() method ,check weather is it work or not,if it work then the problem is dialog fragment

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add `OnClickListener` for Imageview in Adapter class like

```
viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
}
```

});

Then after you can access ImageView in `onItemClick` like

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();


if (viewId == R.id.button1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (viewId == R.id.button2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ListView clicked" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!...

Comment: I'm clicking for up vote button but it doesn't change vote number can't understand why.

Comment: Mehul can you explain why you are passing the following three paramiters into
 ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
if i understand clear parent is adapter of listView, V is clicked view in my case image, position is position of image into raw and why ZERO?

Comment: go with this Link :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View, int, long)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem to show a dialog from the adapter. If your adapter needs something that it doesn't have, then you can add a field for your adapter with some listener like `private final OnImageClickListener` and create an interface:

```
public interface OnImageClickListener {
    void onImageClicked(View view, int position, int id);
}
```

When you create the adapter from your activity or a fragment, you can implement this interface either in your activity/fragment or inside an anonymous class, and in there you have access to the fragment manager and can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm i'll use your advice too this could be a second good way to solve my problem