# setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, onclicklistener

My Listview app gets its data and background color of itemview from custom adapter `ListAdapter.class`.i also need to set the currently selected list items value in a `textview` below `listview`,but the `setOnItemClickListener` in `MAinActivity` is not executing.pls help.

This is my list view app:

[Layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw0sG.png)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static ListAdapterclass adapter;
    ListView lv;
    TextView tv2;
    private  final String android_versions[]={
            "Donut",
            "Eclair",
            "Froyo",
            "Gingerbread",
            "Honeycomb",
            "Ice Cream Sandwich",
            "Jelly Bean",
            "KitKat",
            "Lollipop",
            "Marshmallow"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }
    private  void initViews() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected);

        adapter = new ListAdapterclass(getApplicationContext(), android_versions);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("********************** INSIDE  ONITEMCLICKLISTNER IN MAIN ACTIVITY ******************");
                String ver_name = (lv.getItemAtPosition(i)).toString();


                tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected);
                tv2.setText(ver_name);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter.class**

```
public class ListAdapterclass extends ArrayAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private String android_versionNames[];
    Context mContext;
    public int row_index=-1;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int i, long l) {
        int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
        String ver_name=getItem(position).toString();
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
       LinearLayout LL;
        TextView tv2;
    }



    public ListAdapterclass(Context context,String android_versionnames[]) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item,android_versionnames);
        this.android_versionNames=android_versionnames;
        this.mContext=context;

        System.out.println(" ????????????????????????  Inside dataadapter,Android names :  ?????????????????????????????\n  ");
        for(int i=0;i<android_versionnames.length;i++){
            System.out.println("\n"+android_versionnames[i]);
        }

    }
    private int lastPosition=-1;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String ver_name=getItem(position).toString();

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View result;

        if(convertView==null){
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            viewHolder.tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.LL=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_1);
            viewHolder.tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);
            result=convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }
        lastPosition=position;

        viewHolder.tv.setText(ver_name);

        viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                row_index=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if(row_index==position){
            viewHolder.LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#409de1"));
            viewHolder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            viewHolder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.cybraum.test.listviewcolorchange.MainActivity"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     >
 </ListView>


</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight=".2"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout_2"
     android:orientation="horizontal"

     >
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Selected : "
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_gravity="center"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:text="text"
      android:id="@+id/selected"
      android:layout_gravity="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
    android:padding="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: post your adapter item xml

Comment: what happen in a log while you click on an item . anything print in the log

Comment: remove viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener in your adapter and then check is it taking onItemClickListener or not?

Comment: i have added the xml files..

Comment: yes.it worked when i removed viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener..but i need that also..what to do???????

Comment: Now use viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener and add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to your list item main parent layout xml and check. If it is working then fine otherwise check readyandroid answer below that will help you.

Comment: remove implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in adapter class, then try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227424/android-listview-with-clickable-items-in-its-rows-causes-problems-continuing-sc[May be same as your Problem ][1]
Try it

Comment: @Anvi, Why did you implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in adaper class

Comment: i removed AdapterView.OnItemClickListener...still not working

Comment: did  you check any log in console

Comment: use debug to test

Comment: yes i checked..nothing there..

Comment: try  to use android:focusable="true" in android ListView xml &wrap_content

Comment: Thanks guys...finally got the answer from 'Ready Android'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener listener from adapter and
In your adapter add a method to update row_index:

```
public void changeIndex(int rowIndex){
this.row_index = rowIndex;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call this method from onItemClickListener event:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
adapter.changeIndex(i);//This will give you the same result of viewHolder.LL.setOnClickListener as you are doing
                //Do whatever you are doing previously
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take click event from adapter then listview itemclick could not work if you need adapter click event and listview item click please refer the link,
[How to make imageView clickable from OnItemClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672971/how-to-make-imageview-clickable-from-onitemclicklistener/40673034#40673034)

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == R.id.button1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (viewId == R.id.button2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ListView clicked" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**In adapter:**

```
viewHolder.Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("********************** INSIDE  ONITEMCLICKLISTNER IN MAIN ACTIVITY ******************");
                String ver_name = (lv.getItemAtPosition(i)).toString();


                tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected);
                tv2.setText(ver_name);
            }
        });
```

And from adapter remove

implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: See Above  answer that may useful to you,Because we can take onClicke vent and itemclick from Listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your adaptor from the `setOnClickListner()`
Try to change Your method with

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
   Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
   prestationEco str=(prestationEco)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**change listview xml**

```
    <ListView

         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:clickable="true"   
         android:focusable="true">

 </ListView>
```

**remove AdapterView.OnItemClickListener from adapter class**

public class ListAdapterclass extends ArrayAdapter {

}

Answer (score 0):

**change listview xml**

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"></ListView>
```

**remove AdapterView.OnItemClickListener from adapter class**

public class ListAdapterclass extends ArrayAdapter {

}